# How can I make SQL Developer/SQL+ prompt only once for a substitution variable that occurs multiple times in a single statement?

Tags: sql, plsql, variables, substitution

I have a query roughly like this:

```
 select * 
  from A_TABLE 
  where A_COLUMN = '&aVariable'
    union
 select * 
  from A_TABLE 
  where B_COLUMN = '&aVariable';
```

But when I run it, SQL Developer prompts me for the variable twice, even though it's the same variable.

If there's a way to make it prompt only once for a variable that is used twice, how do I do it?

I do **not** want to use a script, it must be a single executable query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I was forming this post, I figured out how to do it:

```
 :a_var
 select * 
  from A_TABLE 
  where A_COLUMN = :a_var
    union
 select * 
  from A_TABLE 
  where B_COLUMN = :a_var;
```

SQL Developer will then prompt for a bind variable, you can enter it and hit apply.

Answer (score 7):

```
select * 
  from A_TABLE 
  where A_COLUMN = '&aVariable'
    union
 select * 
  from A_TABLE 
  where B_COLUMN = '&&aVariable';
```

Notice how the 2nd (and subsequent) variables will use double-ampersand (&&)

Comment: if after you are done and want another value after you commit use this undefine aVariable;

Answer (score 3):

I know you found another way to do it, but FYI the basic answer is that if you double up the ampersand (e.g., use '&&aVariable'), then the value you enter for the substitution variable will be remembered for the length of your session.  Note that in this case if you re-execute the query you will not be prompted again, it will keep using the same value.

Comment: This isn't ideal since the most frequent use case is running the query repeatedly with various values.  Secondly, using bind variables as I did will result in better performance since the query can be cached in the shared pool and reused with different values without being parsed anew.

Comment: The &&-method is ideal for DDL-scripts

Comment: How do you force the `&&variable` to prompt for a new value?

Comment: @craig You'd either have to close your database session and open a new one, or explicitly undefine the variable.  In SQLPlus, the latter would be `UNDEFINE variable`; off the top of my head, not sure if the same would work in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

So when you use & substitution you are just using the single & as a faster way instead of having to type a value over again. By using the && the value becomes locked-in to the variable name. So &&variable would be different from &&variable1. By doing it this way you will be prompted once and that value you inputted will be adhered to that variable name. Simply put if you write your code like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A_TABLE
WHERE A_COLUMN = '&&aVariable1'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM A_TABLE
WHERE B_COLUMN ='&&aVariable2';
```

Then if you wanted to use a different set of values you will have to change the variable name to something like this '&&aVariable3' and '&&aVariable4' should be sufficient for another set.

Answer (score 0):

```
ACCEPT variableToPrompt PROMPT "Enter variable" DEFAULT "test";

SELECT
    *
FROM    
    TABLE
WHERE
    COLUMN = '&variableToPrompt'
```

> Note that the ' in '&variableToPrompt' is only required if your variable is a string.
>   The default value is optional.