# One input multiple queries

Tags: oracle, input, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

I'm sure this is such a simple answer but I'm new to this and haven't been able to either ask the question of Google or anything in the right way.

I have a query, utilising the same input multiple times, and what I need to know is how can I get the input only once to be used several times?

ie the last line of the below is used at least five times and my current format asks it five times

Partial fix in place (Thank you  Kaushik Nayak and your answer) now but it doesn't work correctly. I think the several join are where I have the issue, the initial select for the value of v.dt appears fine

```
FROM Bmtrread Rd 
INNER JOIN CUSTIMA.BSVCHRGE
ON Rd.CUST_REF = CUSTIMA.BSVCHRGE.U##CUST_REF
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM Bsvchrge Ch t cross join v
WHERE Rd.CUST_REF     = Ch.U##CUST_REF
AND Ch.U##TARIFF_CODE = 'TB12'
AND Ch.CHG_PERCENT    = 1
AND Rd.CURREAD_DT    >= v.dt
```

Comment: Is this statement run in SQL*Plus?

Comment: No. Running it in Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/735429/409172) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single with clause to get the desired value and then use the column everywhere in the select or where clause

```
with v(dt)
AS
(
select to_date('&Start_Read_Date_DD_MM_YYYY','DD/MM/YYYY') from dual
)
select ..  --your select statement
..
FROM Bmtrread Rd 
INNER JOIN CUSTIMA.BSVCHRGE
ON Rd.CUST_REF = CUSTIMA.BSVCHRGE.U##CUST_REF
cross join v --add here
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM Bsvchrge Ch 
WHERE Rd.CUST_REF     = Ch.U##CUST_REF
AND Ch.U##TARIFF_CODE = 'TB12'
AND Ch.CHG_PERCENT    = 1
AND Rd.CURREAD_DT    >= v.dt --replace it with v.dt in all places.
)
```

Comment: I take it the "sometable" should be the table I am querying and the "t cross join v" adds the ability to use the parameter? (or am I confused lol)

Comment: @Vukoneti : yes `t` is just an alias I used for your table, that's all. It could be `rd` or `ch` or whatever you wish . See edits

Comment: I think I'm more confused as there are existing joins, and I'm not even sure how to properly post the code here :)

Comment: @Vukoneti : There's no reason for confusion. simply put the `cross join v`  after all your join conditions. Or else edit your question and add your complete query, at least starting from `from clause`

Comment: @Vukoneti : Please check my edits. You should include cross join in the main `from` so that it could be utilised within an external `where clause` as well as inside the  `exists( .. )`

Comment: Thank you. Got it working after figuring out how I was using your solution wrong :) Very much appreciated