# How to set variabel In Toad for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, toad

How to Set variabel call in toad for orcale?
Like i have Query for input 3 report_dat, and 1 want create variable, so that i only input once

I have create like this

```
def report_date = 2;
def report_year = 2021;
```

and in where condition, i have set like this.

```
where H_CLOSING_PERIOD.BULAN = &report_date
and H_CLOSING_PERIOD.TAHUN = &report_year
```

But, when i run that query, it's still request input from user, like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvCgT.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make SQL Developer/SQL+ prompt only once for a substitution variable that occurs multiple times in a single statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735429/how-can-i-make-sql-developer-sql-prompt-only-once-for-a-substitution-variable-t)

Comment: @astentx I think no,
i want to declare a variable, and set value of variable, so that i can set the variable on where condition or call the variable on the sql statement

Comment: `set define off`?

Comment: @astentx would ypu like to give me the example?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing with the following:

```
variable report_date H_CLOSING_PERIOD.BULAN%TYPE; --not sure of your data types, you can adjust these
variable report_year H_CLOSING_PERIOD.TAHUN%TYPE;

SELECT 2
     , 2021
  INTO :report_date
     , :report_year
  FROM dual;
```

and then when you use the binds:

```
WHERE H_CLOSING_PERIOD.BULAN = :report_date
  AND H_CLOSING_PERIOD.TAHUN = :report_year
```

Answer (score 0):

In TOAD, the simplest way (from my point of view), is to use bind variables. How? Simply precede their names with a colon sign:

```
where H_CLOSING_PERIOD.BULAN = :report_date
  and H_CLOSING_PERIOD.TAHUN = :report_year
```

TOAD will prompt you to enter their values. For any subsequent execution, just hit ENTER (i.e. you don't have to enter their values, unless you want to).